# backbone model.parse not consistently called during collection.parse

Tags: backbone.js

In most of my cases, the model.parse is called during a collection.parse. In some cases the model.parse isnt called.

I need it in all cases. Is it possible to place it somewhere global as in the similar option:  `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;`

Also the docs offer seemingly conflicting info regarding model.parse

> model.parse(response, options)
>
> parse is called **whenever** a model's data is returned by the server, in fetch, and save.

versus and possible/maybe

> model.initialize
>    ...
>    **If** {parse: true} is passed as an option, the attributes will first be
>   converted by parse before being set on the model.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. i solved it. seems the official docs are confusing.  here is a more concise description of when and where to use parse: true options.

http://adzdavies.blogspot.ca/2012/08/backbone-parsing.html